# Query for time ranges of values from beginning-dates of values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I had a table of values which validity starts at start-date, like this:

```
select x.*
into #t
from
(select 15 as value, '2012.05.20' as start-datedate
union
select 15, '2012.06.20'
union
select 15, '2012.07.20'
union
select 16, '2012.08.20'
union
select 17, '2012.09.20'
union
select 15, '2012.11.20'
union
select 17, '2012.12.20'
) x
```

So table looks like this:

```
select * from #t order by date

value   start-date
-----------------------------
15      2012.05.20
15      2012.06.20
15      2012.07.20
16      2012.08.20
17      2012.09.20
15      2012.11.20
17      2012.12.20
```

My problem is how to make a table of time periods where each of value was valid. It should look like this:

```
value       start_date      end_date
15        2012.05.20       2012.08.20
16          2012.08.20  2012.09.20
17          2012.09.20  2012.11.20
15          2012.11.20  2012.12.20
17          2012.12.20
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the input data in #t for the output interval `17 2012.09.20 2012.11.20`? Shouldn't this be `17 2012.09.20 2012.10.20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but think it does what you're after: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21691

```
select value, min(startdate) start_date, nextDate end_date
from
(
  select value
  , startdate
  , (
    select min(startdate) 
    from #t t2 
    where t2.value != t1.value
    and t2.startdate > t1.startdate 
  ) nextDate
  from #t t1
) y
group by value, nextDate
order by start_date
```

Comment: This doesn't work if intervals are broken. Just remove `select 15, '2012.07.20'` from testdata and the first interval of value 15 still is given as `15 2012.05.20 2012.08.20`

Comment: Hey @Nico - It depends on the requirements.  I'd interpreted the end date as being the first date on which the value field changes (hence the last record in the expected results having no end date - because there's not yet been a change of value).  I think you're taking the requirement to mean the end date should be 1 month after the last start date; in which case I confirm my solution wouldn't work for that requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much John! This was what I need. Intervals will not be broken because start-date of a new value is an end date of an old value. That is the way it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table #t

select x.*
into #t
from
(select 15 as value, cast( '2012.05.20' as date ) as startdate
union
select 15, '2012.06.20'
union
select 15, '2012.07.20'
union
select 15, '2012.11.20'
union
select 17, '2012.12.20'
union
select 17, '2012.09.20'
union
select 16, '2012.08.20'
) x

;with "cte"
as
(
    select  
        rank() over ( partition by t1."value" order by t1."startdate" ) as "rank"
        , t1."value"
        , t1."startdate"
        , ISNULL ( t2."startdate", dateadd( month, 1, cast( t1."startdate" as date ))) as "enddate"
    from #t as t1
    left join #t as t2
        on 1 = 1
        and t1."value" = t2."value"
        and datediff( month, t1."startdate", t2."startdate" ) = 1
)
, "cte2"
as
(
    select
        c1.value
        , c1."startdate" 
        , c1."enddate" 
    from 
        cte c1
    left join
        cte c2
        on 1 = 1
        and c1."rank" + 1 = c2."rank"
        and c1."value" = c2."value"
)
, "cte3"
as
(
    select
        value, startdate
    from cte2

    union all

    select
        value, enddate
    from cte2
)
, "cte4"
as
(
    select 
        * 
        , count( 1 ) over ( partition by value, startdate ) as "no"
    from 
        cte3 
)
, "cte5"
as
(
select
    row_number() over ( partition by "value" order by "startdate" ) as "rn"
    , *
from
    cte4
where
    "no" = 1
)
select
    c1."value"
    , c1."startdate"
    , c2."startdate" as "endtime"
from
    cte5 as c1
    inner join cte5 as c2
    on 
        1 = 1
        and c1."rn" + 1 = c2."rn"
        and c1."value" = c2."value"
        and c1."rn" % 2 = 1
order by
    "value"
    , "startdate"
```

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21756/0)